# Convert List to 2D array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a list:

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
```

I added some string using the .Add() function.
How do I convert it to a 2D array?

Thanks!

Comment: What should the 2 dimensions be? You have a one dimensional list, you need to write the code that determines how it should be split up

Comment: Pavel Anikhouski no, i tried that. I want an array of chars like: char[,] test =new char[3,2];

Comment: Please, share what have you tried and expected input/output

Comment: This question is closed, so I can't answer this directly, but you need these lines of code:
`public char[][] ConvertToArray(List<string> MyList)
    {
       var size=MyList.Count;
       var array=new char[size][];
       for(int i=0;i<MyList.Count;i++)
       {
        array[i]=MyList[i].ToCharArray();
       }
       return array;
      }`